# Speed up row and column wise operation in R

Tags: r

Using the reprex data below, the operation is straightforward:

1. For `row,i` and `column,j` combination in `df`, subset the corresponding cluster associated with `df[i,j]`
2. Pull a sample size of 1 or size >1 for the `Value` variable in the `cluster_data` dataframe from cluster id in step 1.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 until `i` equals `nrow(df)`

My working for loop code is posted below.  The for loop I wrote works fine for smaller datasets but takes quite a while larger datasets. I imagine there's a much better and faster way (performance based) to code this operation for large datasets but the best I've come up with is to loop through each row / column given that my sampling in Step 2 is conditional on the value corresponding to the row / column index from Step 1.  I would like someone to suggest a faster approach than my for loop solution.  I don't have any requirements on whether it needs to be base `R` or rely on other libraries.  I'm mainly after the fastest achievable solution.

My actual dataset can range anywhere from 500,000 rows to 2 million rows and the number of clusters varies quite a bit but doesn't typically exceed more than 50.  It is likely, however, that I may have datasets that have more than 50 clusters.

**Sample dataframe:**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
7, 8, 4, 7, 8, 7, 3, 8, 8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7), V2 = c(7, 6, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 4, 7, 7, 
7, 6, 7, 4, 7, 6, 7, 6, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 4, 8, 
7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 8, 6, 6, 7, 3, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
6, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 4, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 
7), V3 = c(7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 
7, 7, 6, 4, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 6, 4, 4, 7, 4, 4, 7, 
7, 7, 6, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 
7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7, 4, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7), 
    V4 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 
    7, 4, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 6, 4, 4, 7, 6, 3, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 7, 
    6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 7, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 
    6, 4, 1, 6, 6, 6, 7), V5 = c(4, 4, 8, 8, 7, 4, 7, 4, 8, 4, 
    4, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 4, 4, 8, 7, 
    7, 8, 4, 8, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 4, 4, 7, 4, 4, 8, 8, 
    7, 4, 8, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7, 6, 
    7, 8, 6, 4, 4, 8, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 4, 6, 4, 
    7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 4, 4, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4), V6 = c(6, 6, 7, 
    6, 6, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 6, 
    4, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 4, 6, 
    6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
    4, 6), V7 = c(9, 5, 9, 5, 5, 8, 9, 5, 9, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 8, 
    5, 8, 9, 5, 8, 8, 9, 5, 8, 8, 8, 5, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 5, 8, 
    8, 9, 8, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 8, 8, 9, 4, 4, 8, 4, 9, 8, 8, 
    5, 9, 8, 9, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 4, 5, 5, 9, 8, 5, 9, 8, 5, 5, 
    9, 8, 8, 6, 5, 9, 4, 9, 5, 9, 4, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 8, 8, 4, 
    8, 5, 8, 8, 5, 8, 5, 8, 9), V8 = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 4, 9, 
    3, 9, 9, 9, 4, 6, 4, 9, 5, 6, 4, 9, 4, 4, 9, 6, 6, 6, 9, 
    9, 6, 4, 9, 4, 4, 6, 9, 4, 2, 6, 9, 4, 4, 4, 9, 5, 6, 4, 
    2, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 9, 4, 9, 9, 9, 6, 4, 9, 
    9, 6, 9, 9, 9, 6, 2, 9, 2, 3, 4, 9, 9, 9, 6, 9, 4, 6, 9, 
    9, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 9), V9 = c(5, 
    5, 9, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 9, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9, 2, 2, 
    5, 5, 5, 2, 9, 2, 5, 5, 9, 5, 5, 5, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 2, 
    5, 5, 9, 5, 9, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 5, 9, 9, 9, 5, 9, 2, 9, 5, 
    9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 5, 9, 9, 2, 
    5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 5, 5, 9, 2, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 5, 
    9, 9, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Sample cluster data:**

```
cluster_data <- structure(list(cluster = c(4L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 
4L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L), Value = c(30.6, 
24.3, 35.1, 30.3, 28.1, 23.5, 39, 37, 23.5, 23.6, 39.2, 18.1, 
33.6, 32.1, 20.2, 15.7, 66.6, 18.8, 21.7, 17.7, 33.1, 5.4, 3.2, 
44.1, 14.5, 30.7, 21.9, 14.5, 21.9, 22.6, 24.4, 36.4, 18.8, 6.2, 
20.3, 26, 31.9, 13.2, 16.9, 14.2, 38, 10, 29.4, 34.1, 54.3, 22, 
37.2, 14.4, 8.2, 15.5, 25.1, 36.3, 6, 18.3, 14.1, 16.8, 27.6, 
21.7, 9.3, 39.8, 28, 8.4, 7.3, 26, 70.1, 24.9, 26.1, 11.9, 43.1, 
42.1, 5.7, 29.7, 9.4, 50.4, 23.6, 23.3, 14.7, 24.2, 33.6, 20.5, 
48.5, 38.5, 21.6, 11.6, 26.4, 18.5, 38.2, 35.9, 57.3, 21.5, 8.2, 
23.3, 31.6, 27.4, 17.9, 0.5, 6, 26.3, 10.9, 1.6)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Working for loop code:**

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
    clusterId <- df[i,j]
    df[i,j] <- sample(cluster_data[cluster_data$cluster==clusterId,"Value"], size = 1)
  }
  print(paste0("Finished iterating over row ",i,"."))
}
df$clusterSum <- rowSums(df)
```

Comment: "Fastest" will depend on the dimensions of your larger datasets, can you be more specific about your use case? How many unique clusters and how big are they in the two data sets?

Comment: As a note, funny enough that `print()` line may actually be a major performance drag. I'm not saying its the root cause of your problems, but it is likely slowing things down.

Comment: @JonSpring I have updated my response to include dimensions of my real dataset.

Comment: @Adam good point on the call to `print()`; that actually shaves off close to a 1 minute on a test dataset that took 3.5 minutes to complete with the call to `print()` to 2.5 minutes to complete without the call to `print()`.

Comment: How many items in each cluster to sample from?

Comment: @JonSpring the number of observations per cluster will vary based on the dataset but several thousands per cluster. The test dataset that I'm using for benchmark purposes has ~220,000 rows with 9 clusters. Number of observations per cluster in this dataset ranges from ~1,200 to ~10,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed up by grouping cluster values (no need to filter multiple times for same thing) using `split`:

```
cluster_data <- lapply(split(cluster_data, cluster_data$cluster), function(x) x$Value)
df <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) sapply(x, function(x) sample(cluster_data[[x]], 1))))
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$row_sum <- rowSums(df)
```

Another way is to find indices of clusters within `df` and then sample only once for each cluster:

```
df <- as.matrix(df)
indices <- split(seq_along(df), df)
cluster_data <- lapply(split(cluster_data, cluster_data$cluster), function(x) x$Value)
for(i in seq_along(indices))
  df[indices[[i]]] <- sample(cluster_data[[names(indices)[[i]]]], length(indices[[i]]), TRUE)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$row_sum <- rowSums(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. Both of your codes are a significant improvement to my for loop.  The second code with indices is significantly faster. However, when I `set.seed(111)` to try and reproduce the same `rowSums` values I get different values between my for loop results and your first and second code. Shouldn't all three code chunks produce the same `rowSums`? Also, I think `df <- as.data.frame(df)` is needed between line 2 and 3 of your first code because a `t(apply(...` produces a matrix that is coerced into a list by `rowSums`.

Comment: It's probably because the calling order of `sample` function is different. It also has different arguments - sampling with replacement. For example try `set.seed(123)` with `sample(1:4, 3)` & `sample(1:4, 3, TRUE)`

Comment: could you suggest a solution for sampling more than `Value` from each cluster? Originally, I need to be able to select only one sample but I will need a solution that is a little more flexible with respect to sampling size.  I know I can wrap both your answers in a for-loop and run `x` number of times to get more than one sample but that would be slow and I think inefficient. I have updated my question to reflect that I need to be able to select 1 or >1 samples for `Value`. Thank you.